# Make section style bold

Tags: sectioning

I have the following style for a section. How can i make it bold please:

```
\def\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}{-2.0ex plus
    -0.5ex minus -.2ex}{1.5ex plus 0.3ex
minus0.2ex}{\Large\sc\raggedright}}
```

Comment: Note that `\sc` has been obsolete since 1993! Use `\scshape`. But here is also your problem. You're looking for `\scshape\bfseries`, but very few fonts are available in bold small caps